# SQL connection string ignoring specified username & password?

Tags: asp.net, sql, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, connection-string

I’m having a problem with my SQL Connection strings not using the authentication provided in the connection string. I have written an ASP.NET application using self-tracking entities and I need to access data from two different servers. The first server, SQLSERVER1 is using windows authentication and is on the domain and im able to pull my data just fine. The second server connection however, is on another box off the domain and I need to use a specific login and password to access the data. I confirmed that the credentials im using in the connection string can connect to the server just fine.

On my web-server setup I have my app pool in IIS7 running under its own credential “Domain\AppPoolUser”.

For some reason, whenever I try to call data from SQLSERVER2 after publishing to the webserver im getting the following error, even though I have specified the credentials in my connection string and they are valid. The connection works fine however, if im debugging the application locally : **Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\AppPoolUser'.**

It seems like it’s not using the credentials I have specified in the connection string, and instead trying to connect as the application pools credentials. How can I setup the connection string to use the credentials I have provided?
Here is my connection strings:

```
<add name="ADATrackingContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server=SQLSERVER1;Database=ADATracking;Integrated Security=True;" />  
<add name="PatientContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server=SQLSERVER2;Database=Patients;uid=PatientUser;password=123456;Integrated Security=False;" />
```

Comment: Which context is the error coming from?  If it's ADATrackingContext, then this is understandable, because you're using Integrated Security on that connection.

Comment: ADATrackingContext is working properly with window authentication. The error is coming from PatientContext.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear in my original question. The problem connection string is PatientContext.

Comment: Where is the PatientContext classes created? In the ASP.Net website/web application or in a class library that is referenced by the ASP.NET site? If it's in a class library, it might be using a connection string from the class library which was created at design time. Are you using integrated security for the PatientContext when debugging in dev env?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the error was being caused beacuse I was trying to pull the data before my client page was authenticated to the ADATracking connection string. I moved the data call over to the HomeConstroller.cs instead of the Global.asax file and all is working now. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it matters, but the user should be `User Id=` and not `uid=`

Answer (score 0):

The ADATrackingContext connection string will attempt to login using the Domain\AppPoolUser domain account since you have set the Integrated Security = true. Since you don't have Domain\AppPoolUser as a login for your db, you will get the error you describe.

Double check to make sure you are passing the correct connection string to your DbContext.

Comment: The ADATrackingContext is working correctly as you describe to hit the first server. Im having problems with the PatientContext connection string. Just double checked the string im sending to the DbContext and it is correct.

Comment: For further clarification, im using Code-First developmnent. My Context classes are the same name as my connection strings. Im just running a simple linq query on both contexts to push the data to a list.